# Query a MongoDB collection using pyspark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am building an application utilizing PHP with  **MongoDB** as a database.One of collection across DB has massive volume of data i.e **8GB** data.
I perform **aggregate** operation on data stored in MongoDB collection and accordingly generate statistics .
But processing huge volume of data takes a long duration.Hence I opted for [Apache spark](http://spark.apache.org/) to process data stored in **MongDB collection**
I have configured [MongoDB spark connector](https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/) and executed a demo script in **python** to fetch data from mongo collection through spark.

Following is python code snippet

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
conf=SparkConf()
conf.set('spark.mongodb.input.uri','mongodb://[host]/db.collection')
conf.set('spark.mongodb.output.uri','mongodb://[host]/db.collection')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
df.printSchema()
df.registerTempTable("mycollection")
result_data=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from mycollection limit 10")
result_data.show()
```

In above code snippet I have utilized [pyspark.sql module](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql) to generate **RDD**.
But generation of **RDD** incurs reading of all data from collection which takes a long duration to read massive volume of data as opposed to principle on which **Apache Spark** works.
Hence suggest me an appropriate solution to **read data from Mongo collection using pyspark with optimal performance** and also if any **alternate package in Apache spark** exists to **communicate with MongoDB**.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, unlike filters the limit clause is not passed back to the Mongo Spark Connector so it cannot be automatically converted into an aggregation pipeline stage.

However, you can always supply your own pipeline stage like so eg:

```
dfr = sqlContext.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource")
df = dfr.option("pipeline", "[{ $limit: 10 }]").load()
```

Comment: Thank you for offering a remarkable solution.I need to read only selected documents from mongo collection into a data frame and there after apply aggregate operation upon them